# Publishing JointStates in ROS with Gazebo

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am loading a SDF into Gazebo using the `gazebo_ros/spawn_model`. I am loading a `joint_state_controller` through the `controller_manager` and its even publishing a `joint_state` message. However, there are no joints listed in the `joint_state` message despite it containing multiple not-fixed joints.

Any ideas how to make the joint_state message include the proper joints?

**Edit**:

SDF Snippet:

```
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
  <robotNamespace>valve</robotNamespace>
</plugin>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6816/publishing-jointstates-in-ros-with-gazebo/) by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2014-08-13**:
this is using gazebo_ros_control?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on 2014-08-13**:
Yes, see edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am not absolute sure about this but I think this plugin requires an URDF to work correctly. the `gazebo_ros_control` plugin will block until it gets the urdf from the server( method `getURDF` from  [`gazebo_ros_control_plugin.cpp`](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/hydro-devel/gazebo_ros_control/src/gazebo_ros_control_plugin.cpp) )

I guess this causes your problems...

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on 2014-08-14**:
This looks promising, because I have a URDF, but it wasn't under the default robot_description parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Do you have a .yaml file that you load with the controller manager that includes:

```
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 50
```

?

In my launch file for Baxter I have:

```
<!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
<rosparam file="$(find baxter_control)/config/gazebo_controllers.yaml" command="load"/>

<!-- load the default controllers -->
<node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
      output="screen" ns="/robot" args="joint_state_controller                                                                                            
                                        right_position_trajectory_controller                                                                              
                                        left_position_trajectory_controller                                                                               
                                        " />
```

I haven't worked with Gazebo / ros_control in a while though, so my memory is hazy.

---

Originally posted by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) with karma: 369 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on 2014-08-14**:
Yes, I include that info in the parameter server. The problem is it doesn't publish any joints.